# Trouble adding image to Visualforce page rendred as PDF

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I'm attempting to add my company logo to a visual force page, which is then being rendered as a pdf, but have not been successful

Logo.zip is a static ressource 
images.jpg is the logo within the zip file

```
<DIV TYPE="HEADER">
    <P ALIGN="RIGHT" STYLE="margin-bottom: 0.45in; line-height: 100%">
        <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.Logo,'images.jpg')}"  WIDTH="113" HEIGHT="65" />
    </P>
</DIV>
```

Any idea?

Comment: I usually use something like <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Logo,'images.jpg')}"  WIDTH="113" HEIGHT="65" /> and have this working in pdf docs. Could it be a problem with your <P> style?

Comment: I put it outside <P> style, No change!

Comment: Did you check the image url carefully? if it's just one image try putting `<apex:image id="logo1" url="{!$Resource.imglogo}"/>` where imglogo should direclty your file.

Comment: Yes right! that's what I've told myself too !! And yes its showing up now, thank you @highfive

Comment: Yep with pleasure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `URLFOR($Resource.Logo,'images.jpg')` be careful to put the correct image url. In my opinion if you have only one file, it's better to directly add a static resource to that and set the path as below.

```
<apex:image id="logo1" url="{!$Resource.imglogo}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version I have that works for me.

```
<apex:page  showHeader="false" renderas="pdf" applyHtmlTag="false" standardStylesheets="false">
<html>
<head>
<style>
@page
{
    size: A4 landscape;
    padding-top:80px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;

    @bottom-center
    {
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        content: "Page " counter(page);
        font-size: 10pt;
    }
    @top-left{
        content: element(pageHeader);
    }
}

#pageHeader{
    position:running(pageHeader);
    display: block;
    text-align:left;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
}
body{
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    padding:30px;


}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="pageHeader">
    <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Logo)}" width="100px;"/>
</div>


</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Does the image show up correctly in an html rendered page? change renderAs to html to check.