# Problem adding css to Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, css

Inline css is working. But I'm unable to call from an external css the same code.

Following is in VF..

```
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.style, 'style.css')}"/>
```

And my style.css content in Static Resource...

```
  <style type="text/css">
   div.col1{
   background-color: #ccffcc;
   }
   div{
       float:left;
      }
       div.border{

      border-style:outset;
      border-width:6px;
      }
     .errorClass {
      background-color: red;
     }
    .normalClass {
     background-color: green;
     }
    .inProgressClass {
    background-color: #33CCFF;
    }
   .centerClass
    {
    align:center;
   }
  </style>
```

Comment: What exactly you can't call? A whole css file or just individual classes? If it is a whole css file problem i think this is related to the question about adding images ([look here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32984/trouble-adding-image-to-visualforce-page-rendred-as-pdf))

Comment: I have a color coding in a data table where "errorClass ", "normalClass" colors a cell. I have no images. If I paste it inside VF, it works, but if I use it in static resource nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URLFOR is used when style sheet exist under zipped folder. In your case try this:

`<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.style}"/>`

Comment: Yes @jaffer. You are correct. It's working

Comment: Cool..Please mark it solved so other can see .. Cheers :)

Comment: Wait for 3 more minutes :P

Comment: 29 minutes are gone:P

Comment: I'm sorry. Done =)